# FireFox cannot get mouse position on drag

Tags: firefox, drag-and-drop, element-binding

I have the following code in Angular

```
element.bind('dragstart', function(){ // set the drag start parameter});
element.bind('dragend', function(){ // set the drag end parameter});
element.bind('drag, function(event){
    console.log(event.originalEvent.pageY);
});
```

However, this just returns the same number no matter what. If I stop dragging, and restart dragging, then it returns the `pageY` when the drag started and stays on that number! Why?